# get collection names through HTTP interface

Tags: mongodb

I would like to get collections' names with any HTTP interface available here : https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-interfaces

I tried with the simple API REST but I can only get databases' names and the number of collections, but not their name.

I also tried to use sleepy mongoose but I'm not really sure what I'm doing with this API so...

I ask this because I would like to have a HTTP Interface where the user can select one DB then the web-page displays every collections of this DB.

Thanks in advance ! I hope I was enough clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by using *system.namespaces*

http://127.0.0.1:28017/test/system.namespaces/